# Printing a value to input tag with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem with printing a text string to a input tag.

The javascript:

```
imgDiv.innerHTML += "<input type='text' value=" + text[i].firstChild.data + ">";
```

The generated html looks like this:

```
<input type="text" fjäril="" svart="" och="" orange="" value="En">
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value` attribute's value should be also wrapped in quotes (like you did with `type` attribute):

```
imgDiv.innerHTML += '<input type="text" value="' + text[i].firstChild.data + '">';
```